# I see no change after deploying to google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans

I have set up a project with Google App Engine this one : http://podcom-191901.appspot.com/
(I have not payed for Google Cloud services, I did podcom-191901 without registering for a free trial. I also received this notifications:

[image: THIS]

I am following this guide: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/09/how-to-use-the-google-app-engine-with-the-netbeans-ide/

I have

[image: this]

index.jsp:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : 01-13-2018, 03:51:10 AM
    Author     : Molina
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0"
xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
xsi:schemaLocation='http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/downloads/download/schema/appengine-web.xsd appengine-web.xsd'>
    <application>podcom-191901</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <!--    <ssl-enabled>false</ssl-enabled>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    -->
    <threadsafe>false</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

When I "Deploy to Google App Engine" I receive this message:
Reading application configuration data...

```
Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\Molina\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg5035433166099542506.tmp'
5% Warning: Google App Engine Java 7 runtime is deprecated.
8% Warning: See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/java7
11% Scanning for jsp files.
13% Compiling jsp files.
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.
28% Cloning 1 static files.
31% Cloning 25 application files.
40% Uploading 2 files.
52% Uploaded 1 files.
61% Uploaded 2 files.
68% Sending batch containing 2 file(s) totaling 3KB.
73% Initializing precompilation...
90% Deploying new version.
95% Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
98% Uploading index definitions.

Update for module default completed successfully.
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files for module default...
```

But I still don't see any change on the page http://podcom-191901.appspot.com/
It should be "Hello World!" not "Hello, World"

Comment: Is it possible that you deployed a new version while the old one still receives traffic? What do you see on the Versions page? Side notes: the guide you're following is a bit old, using the GAE SDK. Nothing wrong with it if you know what you're doing, only know that now the recommended way is using the Cloud SDK. Also - you seem to have 2 sets of config files in 2 places, careful not to deploy the wrong ones.

Comment: Look at the _Versions_ tab on the _Cloud Console_ (https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) and you may find that you have multiple versions of your app, but 100% of the traffic is being directed to your first version.

Comment: thanks both, you help me a lot. I did not know about versions and clound SDK works much better thanks again.